# Apple Watch app fails to install on device

Tags: apple-watch, watchos

I’m working on an Apple Watch app and see that intermittently it fails to install on the Watch. I tried restarting the watch, deleting the app, but still see the issue:

**How do I fix Apple Watch app showing loading progress upon install, but never appears on the watch face?** (disappears upon install, does not appear on the list of installed apps on the phone Watch app)

[image]